# Can we create multiple servers in the websphere application server profile?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Can we create multiple servers in the websphere application server profile
Usually the default is server1 gets created , when you create the stand alone instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can via wsadmin scripting, check details here:
[Creating a server using scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_createserver.html?lang=en)
however by default to configure and install app on that server you will need to use console installed on server1 or scripting, so it is a bit troublesome. That server will also share some configuration settings with server1 e.g. security settings.

If you want more isolation it is usually easier to just create another Application Server profile, from the same WebSphere installation (using Profile Management Tool, or manageprofiles script).